# Is there a way to subscribe to the uncertainty of Gmapping?

Tags: localization, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to add a bit more localization to the Turtlebot during gmapping via RFID tags, so I have them publishing on the vo for robot_pose_ekf. I have noticed that gmapping runs through the certainty of it's pose in order to determine where it is / read the paper. Is there any way to subscribe to this like it's a topic? I can use this value to train my robot when to trust the RFID tags and when to not, since it's concurrently using them for localization and assigning them positions.

Edit: I'm basically doing SLAM with RFID tags.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39053/is-there-a-way-to-subscribe-to-the-uncertainty-of-gmapping?/) by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-18**:
Yeah, I know about the Entropy, but there are a lot more calculations that aren't published. I'll look into it more. Thanks. The Entropy is relatively static in terms of other calculations going on, from what I've observed, so it isn't much good to me on the move-to-move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [gmapping wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/gmapping) there is a entropy value published which gives some information about the pose uncertainty. Have you tried that?

Other than that, I'm not aware of existing mechanisms. You would probably have to look into that yourself. It shouldn't be too complicated to retrieve the pose estimate for every particle for example, which could then be used to compute a gaussian estimate (e.g. mean and covariance matrix) of the pose array.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roberto3](https://answers.ros.org/users/33776/roberto3/) on 2018-02-21**:
How can you transform  this pose uncertainty from a float64 to a matrix which says the covariance???

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-04-25**:
@roberto3 were you able to get this into a covariance matrix?
@Stefan Kohlbrecher when forming the gaussian estimate (i.e. mean and covariance matrix) of the pose array, do you weight the mean by the particle weight?